# Changing value of different columns using a function in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a dataframe:

```
A B C
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Now i want to replace 1 with 3, 2 with 7 ,and 3 with 10.

I write the code:

```
df['A'].replace(3, 10, inplace = True)
df['A'].replace(1, 3, inplace = True)
df['A'].replace(2, 7, inplace = True)
```

Works fine for me. I do have to replace 3 with 10 first , because if we change the 1 with 3 first, then the transformed 3 will again changed and finally replaced with 10.

Though i have to replace the same formattion for several columns, how come i use function?

I tried to write one but i failed, any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply this to all columns, you can use

```
to_replace = {3:10, 1:3, 2:7}

df = df.replace(to_replace)
```

which outputs

```
    A   B   C
0   3   3   3
1   7   7   7
2   10  10  10
```

If you want to replace multiple, but not all, you could try

```
df = df.replace({'A' : to_replace, 'B': to_replace})
```

which would outputs.

```
    A   B   C
0   3   3   1
1   7   7   2
2   10  10  3
```

If you have many columns you would like to replace you could use

```
cols = ['A', 'B']

# Then either
df = df.replace({col : to_replace for col in cols})

# or
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.replace(to_replace))
```